# C#: HTML email template font color not working

Tags: c#, html, css

I'm basically trying to create an HTML email message from my C# code. Everything works as expected but when I use font color, then I receive a blank field in my inbox.

My code snippet:

```
string type = "<strong><style=\"color: red; \">" + detail.ToString() + "</style>
</strong>";
```

The type shows correctly when I simply do, type = detail.ToString().
But doesn't work when I add a style. The code simply shows blank word.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<style>` tags are used to define CSS rules. You can't put "content" in them, so this will not work, at all:

```
<style>
   color: red
   <div> Hi mom! </div> <--this line is illegal CSS and will kill the rest of the CSS block </div>
</style>
```

You use style ATTRIBUTES:

```
<strong><span style="color: red">Hi mom!</span></strong>
```

or define rules:

```
<style>
   .red { color: red; }
</style>

<strong><span class="red">Hi mom!</span></strong>
```

Comment: You're simply genius! Thank you! That totally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

As @Marc B said in his answer. You will need to define it directly by using the style property on the html element or by creating a new class and setting the class property on the html element.

---

I think you did forgot to set `IsBodyHtml`.

Set:

`MailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;` This allows you to use Html in your e-mails.

Reference:

[MSDN MailMessage.IsBodyHtml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml(v=vs.110).aspx)